# How to get a reference to a non-default ProfileBase in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, profile

I know I can get a reference to the default Profile in ASP.NET with code like this:

```
ProfileBase p = ProfileBase.Create(username);
```

(I know there is also HttpContext.Current.Profile, but that is for the current user, and I need to get the profile by username.)

The above code works only for the DEFAULT provider as defined in the defaultProvider attribute in web.config:

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProfileProvider">
<providers>
 <clear />
 <add applicationName="Gallery Server Pro" connectionStringName="SQLiteDbConnection"
 name="SQLiteProfileProvider"     type="GalleryServerPro.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProfileProvider" />
 <add applicationName="Gallery Server Pro" connectionStringName="SqlServerDbConnection"
 name="SqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" />
</providers>
<properties>
 <add name="ShowMediaObjectMetadata" defaultValue="false" type="String" allowAnonymous="true" />
 <add name="UserAlbumId" defaultValue="0" type="Int32" allowAnonymous="false" />
 <add name="EnableUserAlbum" defaultValue="true" type="String" allowAnonymous="false" />
</properties>
</profile>
```

How would I get a reference to a non-default provider? For example, the provider named SQLiteProfileProvider shown above? I have it working for roles and membership:

```
RoleProvider rp = Roles.Providers["SQLiteRoleProvider"];
```

But the Profile object model is different and I can't figure it out. Thanks for any help!

Roger Martin

[Gallery Server Pro](http://www.galleryserverpro.com)

Answer (score -2):

Use ProfileManager class in .net framework